# How do I set the DispayMember and ValueMember Properties of a ComboBox w/ DataSource set to an Object using Powershell?

Tags: .net, winforms, powershell, combobox

What I am trying to do doesn't seem like it should be that hard but I can't seem to get it to work.  I have comboboxes in use elsewhere using a dataset as the datasoure that work just fine but in this case I wanted to use an object.

Here are the relevant portions of my code generalized.

The Object:

```
$RemoteScript = {Get-ADUser -Filter {enabled -eq $true} -SearchBase "OU=Users,DC=DOMAIN,DC=local" }
# Returns an ADUser Object
$CurrentUsers = Invoke-Command -Session $mySession -ScriptBlock $RemoteScript
```

The above block of code returns the ADUser object with the following relevant properties:

```
DistinguishedName
Name
UserPrincipalName
```

The Following Code attaches the Data to my combobox:

```
$cbComboBox.ValueMember = "UserPrincipalName"
$cbComboBox.DisplayMember = "Name"
$cbComboBox.DataSource = $CurrentUsers
```

When the combobox displays, it uses the "DistinguishedName" to populate the Display and Value members rather than the members I have specified.  I can force it to use a single value using `$cbComboBox.DataSource = $CurrentUsers.Name` but that would leave me looping through the `$CurrentUsers` with a `ForEach` to extract the "UserPrincipalName".

What am I missing?

**EDIT**
To clarify the loop I was referring to.
The above code should display the Name property to the user.  In the button handler I was planning to use `$cbComboBox.SelectedValue` to grap the "UserPrincipalName" from the combobox. Since the combobox is not recognizing the `ValueMember` or the `DisplayMember` properties, the  `SelectedVlaue` is returning the `DistinguishedName` property instead.

If I can't get the combobox to work properly I will have to force the `Name` property as I mentioned above and put the following code in the button handler instead.

```
ForEach ($User in $CurrentUsers) {
    If ($User.Name -eq $cbComboBox.SelectedValue) { 
        $myUser = $User.UserPrincipal
    }
}
```

Comment: Try as I may I can't follow what you're trying to say with it forcing you to loop through with a foreach. Why would it do that? Can you post the code you are referring to?

Comment: See my edits above.  I hope that helps you understand what I am trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

No loop needed, just do something like this:

```
$myUser = $CurrentUsers | Where{$_.Name -eq $cbComboBox.SelectedValue} | Select -ExpandProperty UserPrincipal
```

Comment: Granted, that is better than the foreach (wish I thought of it) but it does not solve the issue with the combobox. If, at the very least, the  combobox does not do what I am trying to do I would like to know why.